# Frontend live-preview in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mathjax, ticket-system

*I am looking for a live-preview functionality like the one here on the Stack exchanges sites.*

I am using a ticket system plugin called [JS support ticket](https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/js-support-ticket/#description) on a Wordpress site. It creates some textareas for the user to write in for posting messages. The plugin uses the built-in Wordpress editor for this, so the user writes and can add bold-face, italic etc. from the wysiwyg editor-menu just as the admin can do inside the admin panel.

I am using the plugin [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) at the same time for math writing. Writing for example

> $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

creates a nicely formatted equation. It is the latex-syntax, and it can be tricky to get right at first try. Therefore I would like to have a **live-preview** right underneath the textarea. So the user can see the final layout of his message before posting.

Exactly as done here on Stack exchange sites.

This seems easier for me to achieve than creating an actual edit-button for the user.

So, all in all I need a field underneath the editor, which updates at every key-stroke **and also renders the MathJax-plugin on the fly**, so that the equation is shown as it will look right after the final dollar sign $ is written in the editor.

Would such functionality be possible?

Comment: Anything is possible! I'm not 100% sure how to go about it, but this plugin does this exact thing for the standard WYSIWYG editor: https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-preview/ It might help to dissect that a little bit and see what they're doing under the hood.

Comment: Aha, thank you for the link. I will look into it